# CGContextDrawPDFPage in landscape mode?

Tags: pdf, ios

Is it possible to render PDF page in landscape mode using CGContextDrawPDFPage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, if you just use basic drawing in a view, and that view is connected to a UIViewController, rotation is already handled for you.

Note that PDF itself also defines rotation, that you may wanna parse and use.

You can use [Apple's QuickLook-API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html) (introduced in iOS4) for a start.